# Shinydashboard: Is it not possible to have nested menu sub items? Can't make it work

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am using a shinydashboard, and have a need to build two-level nested sub menus. I am trying this and won't work:

```
library(shinydashboard)
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id = 'sidebarmenu',
              menuItem('x', tabName = 'x', icon = icon('line-chart')),
              menuItem('y', tabName = 'y',
                       icon = icon('line-chart'),
                       menuSubItem('a',
                                   tabName = 'a',
                                   icon = icon('line-chart')),
                       menuSubItem('b',
                                   tabName = 'b',
                                   icon = icon('line-chart'),
                                   menuSubItem('l',
                                               tabName = 'l',
                                               icon = icon('line-chart')),
                                   menuSubItem('m',
                                               tabName = 'm',
                                               icon = icon('line-chart'))),
                       menuSubItem('c',
                                   tabName = 'c',
                                   icon = icon('line-chart'))
              )))
```

Gives me error:

```
Error in menuSubItem("b", tabName = "b", icon = icon("line-chart"), menuSubItem("l",  : 
  Can't specify both href and tabName
```

Is it possible to build two-level nesting? Of course, removing `l` and `m` sub menus above works just fine (with one level sub menus).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It works if you only use `menuSubItem` as the lowest level, and call the others `menuItem`. Will that work for your purposes?

```
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(id = 'sidebarmenu',
            menuItem('x', tabName = 'x', icon = icon('line-chart')),
            menuItem('y', tabName = 'y',
                     icon = icon('line-chart'),
                     menuItem('a',
                                 tabName = 'a',
                                 icon = icon('line-chart')),
                     menuItem('b',
                                 tabName = 'b',
                                 icon = icon('line-chart'),
                                 menuSubItem('l',
                                             tabName = 'l',
                                             icon = icon('line-chart')),
                                 menuSubItem('m',
                                             tabName = 'm',
                                             icon = icon('line-chart'))),
                     menuItem('c',
                                 tabName = 'c',
                                 icon = icon('line-chart'))
            )))
```

Comment: Very useful. Any idea on how to access the `input$sidebarItemExpanded` corresponding to, for example, the tab `'b'`?